# How to enable error reporting for Java in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio, compiler-errors, settings, line-by-line

When I am writing code in Java language using [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), I am unable to to get in-editor instant error reporting for errors (*squiggles*).

I want to get errors reported before compiling or running my code. Can anyone tell me the correct settings which I can use to get error reporting before running or compiling the code (written in Java), not just in C or C++.

I am unable to find the correct option in VS Code of this setting for Java language.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial check this.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P --> Java: Clean Java Language Server WorkspaceThen restart vscode.

Answer (score 0):

#### Language Support for Java Extension

Please make sure you installed and enabled [Language support for Java ™ for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) extension for Visual Studio Code. The extension should be enabled automatically, when you open your first Java file in the editor.

From the extension's Features section:

> As-you-type reporting of parsing and compilation errors

I reckon this feature you are referring when you mention *squiggles*.

#### Extension Pack for Java

For a better developer experience, I would like to suggest to install the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), which is a collection of useful extensions, curated by Microsoft.

This pack also includes the Language Support for Java Extension, mentioned at the beginning of my answer.

Happy coding!

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P --> Java: Clean Java Language Server WorkspaceThen restart vscode.